# Does asp.net do any caching when checking for [Authorize(Roles = "Student")]

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a method that I would like to limit to use by people who have the role of "Student".  I would like to explore different ways of doing this.

First I know I can decorate the method like this:

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Student")]
```

If I know the role of "Student" has a RoleId of 4 and if I know the user has a UserId of 2 then:

> is decoration of the method more **efficient** than allowing every
>   user into the role and then doing a select against my Identity 2
>   database to see if the user 2 has a roleId of 4 in the AspNetUserRoles
>   table.

As an FYI I am using WebAPI with ASP.Net Identity 2.1 and token bearer authentication. All my users access through web browser front-end. If there is no caching but a way to switch on caching I would appreciate advice from anyone who could help advise me on how to use this if it is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the caching feature of the Role Provider from web.config using `CacheRolesInCookie`. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.cacherolesincookie(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Alternately you can always override the default Role Provider (see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details), but I guess this is not exactly what you are looking after...